# Setting a text field in d3 javascript with a condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to set the .text field with a simple condition:

if (d.name === "") return d.id
else return d.name

Which translates to if the data point has no name then use its id otherwise use its name.

Here is my initial code, where it is always set to the name:

```js
 graph.selectAll("text")
          .data(this.nodes).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(d => d.name)
```

Here is one of the many variations I tried using .each to set the text of each node depending on my condition:

```js
graph.selectAll("text")
          .data(this.nodes).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .each(function (d,i) {
              d3.select(this).text(function(d) {if (d.name === "")
              {return d.id;} 
              else {return d.name;}})})
```

I think I am lacking some understanding in the way I access data in the .each function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `each` you can just use `.text(d => d.name ? d.name : d.id);` or `.text(function(d) {if (d.name) {return d.name;} else {return d.id;)}` if you prefer that style.

Comment: If you want it even shorter, it can be just `.text(d => d.name || d.id);`.

Answer (score 1):

As Robin and Gerardo have stated, there are 3 possible ways to do this:

**First option: `if/else`**

```js
 graph.selectAll("text")
          .data(this.nodes).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(d => {
               if (d.name) {
                  return d.name
               } else {
                  return d.id
               }
             })
```

**Second option: ternary operator**

It's equivalent to if/else, it tests a condition that goes before the `?`, if its true it returns the first term that follows (before the `:`), else it returns the second term that follows (after the ':')

```js
 graph.selectAll("text")
          .data(this.nodes).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(d => d.name ? d.name : d.id)
```

**Third option: Using the logical operator for OR `||`**

Will return the first non-empty option passed to the operator

```js
 graph.selectAll("text")
          .data(this.nodes).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(d => d.name || d.id)
```